# Please explain the last step of this newton method for system of equations

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

[image]

The step of working out x$^1$. I know the above is the formula but do they actually work out the inverse of the derivative matrix, is there a quicker way to do this?

Comment: I think for such small dimension, finding the inverse is the most efficient thing to do. For large dimensional problems, one would use iterative methods for solving linear system, using only a few numbers of iterations, because finding the exact solution is pointless, because its still just an approximation in the primary problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using [Solving a set of equations with Newton-Raphson](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466809/solving-a-set-of-equations-with-newton-raphson/467051#467051) for background.

The regular Newton-Raphson method is initialized with a starting point $x_0$ and then you iterate $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\dfrac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$

In higher dimensions, there is an exact analog. We define:

$$F\left(\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}f_1(x_1, x_2, x_3) \\  f_2(x_1, x_2, x_3)  \\ f_3(x_1, x_2, x_3)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{rcl} x_1^3 x_2-x_3 \\  
5x_1^3 x_3-5x_2&\\  
x_2^3x_3^2-32 \end{array} \end{bmatrix}$$

The derivative of this system is the $3x3$ Jacobian given by:

$$J(x, y, z) = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} & \dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2} & \dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_3}\\ \dfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1} & \dfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2} & \dfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_3} \\ \dfrac{\partial f_3}{\partial x_1} & \dfrac{\partial f_3}{\partial x_2} & \dfrac{\partial f_3}{\partial x_3}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 3 x_1^2 x_2  & x_1^3 &-1 \\ 15 x_1^2 x_3 & -5 & 5 x_1^3 \\ 0 & 3 x_2^2 x_3^2 & 2 x_2^3 x_3 \end{bmatrix}$$

The function $G$ is defined as:

$$G(x) = x - J(x)^{-1}F(x)$$

and the functional Newton-Raphson method for nonlinear systems is given by the iteration procedure that evolves from selecting an initial $x^{(0)}$ and generating for $k \ge 1$,

$$x^{(k)} = G(x^{(k-1)}) = x^{(k-1)} - J(x^{(k-1)})^{-1}F(x^{(k-1)}).$$

We can write this as:

$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1^{(k)}\\x_2^{(k)}\\x_3^{(k)}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}x_1^{(k-1)}\\x_2^{(k-1)}\\x_3^{(k-1)}\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}y_1^{(k-1)}\\y_2^{(k-1)}\\y_3^{(k-1)}\end{bmatrix}$$

where:

$$\begin{bmatrix}y_1^{(k-1)}\\y_2^{(k-1)}\\y_3^{(k-1)}\end{bmatrix}= -\left(J\left(x_1^{(k-1)},x_2^{(k-1)},x_3^{(k-1)}\right)\right)^{-1}F\left(x_1^{(k-1)},x_2^{(k-1)},x_3^{(k-1)}\right)$$

Here is a starting vector:

$$x^{(0)} = \begin{bmatrix}x_1^{(0)}\\x_2^{(0)}\\x_3^{(0)}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0.1\\2.0\\3.0\end{bmatrix}$$

Using this starting value, the iterates are given by:

- $x_0 = (0.1, 2.0, 3.0)$
- $x_1 = (25.475, 2.28528, 1.52479)$
- $x_2 = (16.7237, 2.35526, 1.57156)$
- $x_3 = (11.1596, 2.35117, 1.56911)$
- $x_4 = (7.44242, 2.3506, 1.56967)$
- $x_5 = (4.96763, 2.34871, 1.57156)$
- $x_7 = (3.32525, 2.34244, 1.57786)$
- $x_8 = (2.24692, 2.32233, 1.59819)$
- $x_9 = (1.56361, 2.26486, 1.65773)$
- $x_{10} = (1.17742, 2.14634, 1.78976)$
- $x_{11} = (1.02391, 2.03045, 1.94396)$
- $x_{12} = (1.00041, 2.00083, 1.99775)$
- $x_{13} = (1., 2., 2.)$
- $x_{14} = (1., 2., 2.)$

As you can see, after fourteen iterations, we have:

$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1. \\ 2.\\ 2. \end{bmatrix}$$

Of course, for a different starting vector you are going to get a different solution and perhaps no solution at all.

If we started at $x_0 = (1, 2, 3)$, we converge much faster (three iterations), for example.

**Update** The problem was changed in totality after posting the answer above!

$$F\left(\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}f_1(x_1, x_2, x_3) \\  f_2(x_1, x_2, x_3)  \\ f_3(x_1, x_2, x_3)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{rcl} x_1 +  x_2+ x_3 \\  
x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 - 5\\  
e^{x_1} + x_1 x_2 - x_1 x_3 -1 \end{array} \end{bmatrix}$$

$$J(x, y, z) = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} & \dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2} & \dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_3}\\ \dfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1} & \dfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2} & \dfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_3} \\ \dfrac{\partial f_3}{\partial x_1} & \dfrac{\partial f_3}{\partial x_2} & \dfrac{\partial f_3}{\partial x_3}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1  & 1 & 1 \\ 2 x_1 & 2 x_2 & 2 x_3 \\ e^{x_1} + x_2 - x_3 & x_1 & -x_1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Here is a starting vector:

$$x^{(0)} = \begin{bmatrix}x_1^{(0)}\\x_2^{(0)}\\x_3^{(0)}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}2\\13\\12\end{bmatrix}$$

**Note:** The author has two obvious errors in his first calculation. The first is $2 x_3 = 24$, not $20$ as shown in $a_{23}$. Also, the Jacobian has an incorrect partial derivative term in $J_{31}$, both of which I have corrected  in my answer.

To calculate $x_1$, we have:

$$x_1 = x_0 - J^{-1}(x_0)F(x_0) = \begin{bmatrix}2\\13\\12\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\\ 4 & 26 & 24\\ 1 + e^2 & 2 & -2\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}27\\312\\1 + e^2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-12.5744\\35.2562\\-22.6819\end{bmatrix}$$

Using this starting value, the iterates are given by:

- $x_0 = (2., 13., 12.)$
- $x_1 = (-12.5744,35.2562,-22.6819)$
- $\ldots$
- $x_{11} = (0. , 1.58114 , -1.58114 )$

We converge to:

$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0. \\ 1.58114 \\ -1.58114 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you for that. I do however need to understand how they got it in the example I have given.

Comment: Oh sorry I just realized you answered the previous version.

Comment: Thank you. I just want to know, that jump you made from x0=(2.,13.,12.) to 
x1=(−12.5744,35.2562,−22.6819), how did you work that out?

Comment: I have unticked your anwser to allow you to update it.

Comment: I have uploaded an edited picture, and I think the part I have underlined is wrong. Shouldn't the -x$_1$ be a -x$_3$?

Comment: That is another obvious error. It certainly changes the iterates, including the first one, but surprisingly does not change the final result. That is the second error in the copy! Regardless, it is fixed now in my answer.

Comment: I have posted another  question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1779017/newton-method-iteration and i want to know what program you used to work out your iterates

Comment: Mathematica (I wrote my own code, although it has the methods built-in, I just like control over my routines), but you can find free [*CAS*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems) programs too. Some have online variants - like Maxima and SAGE and many others. Of course, you'd have to find the Newton commands for the task, but many likely have that built in.

Comment: Do you have sympy by any chance?

Comment: No, but I think that is free. Why?

Comment: Ok nvm I just had issues with my computer downloading it. All good